# Javascript function in external file not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a call icon that when clicked should call another function defined in an external JavaScript file

Below is the relevant excerpt from the html code

```
<!--Angular, JQuery and External JS file defined-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vmap.com.au/portal/assets/quickstart.js"></script>

<!--Form with call button-->
<form>
<input id="phone-number" type="hidden" value="<?=$phone?>"/>
<a role="button" id="button-call" type="submit"><i class="icon-call-out"></i></a>
</form>
```

Then we have the external quickstart.js file defined with below sample code

```
$(function () {
const callButton = document.getElementById("button-call");
callButton.onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    makeOutgoingCall();
  };

async function makeOutgoingCall() {
    alert("Test");
    }
});

<!--At the bottom of the page -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am expecting makeOutgoingCall to be called and Test alert to be triggered. But there is no activity in the console, nothing seem to be happening - No errors, no actions.

Comment: silly me - you're using jquery - ignore previous comment - your edit made me look stupid

Comment: do you have any error in your console ?

Comment: is the external file on the same domain? If no, did the external domain set CORS to allow you to access its JS?

Comment: bravo, sorry about that.
@noobforever, I don't see any error in the console.

Comment: @Leilio, I can see the script loaded in the Sources tab in Google Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: Are you sure you've loaded jquery.js in to the page in order for the document.ready to fire and bind the event handler?

Comment: Perhaps *https://vmap.com.au/portal/assets/quickstart.js* is cached. Add a general `console.log` or `alert` to it to check or change the source to something like *https://vmap.com.au/portal/assets/quickstart.js?V=2*

Comment: Does your code work if you make it inline (remove the `script src=` and add `<script>..your code</script>`.  It works fine as provided: https://jsfiddle.net/cw5ej7s4/  note: jsfiddle puts the js at the end of the html, so no need for doc ready there; if your code is as presented, you'll need doc.ready.

Comment: Are you using any sort of framework?  Wordpress? VS asp.net-mvc template?   These can add a *second* jquery at the bottom - after your manually added one at the top - which can blat your code.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, I am using codeigniter php framework. You are right, there are two jquery - one at the top, another at the bottom. Is that an issue? v2.2.4 and v3.4.1

Your code on jsfiddle seems to be working fine. What am I missing? Is it the two JQuery?

Comment: @Lain I will clear the cache and will try again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, in fact two different version of JQuery has been added, so essentially it has been added twice. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Lain - I cleared server cache, browser cache, made changes to the js file, new js version is being reflected in the browser, still no result when clicking the call icon.

Comment: Move your jquery script src= and quickstart.js to the very end of your html - hopefully it will be after the framework one.

Comment: See if there's a configuration for codeigniter to not include jquery

Comment: Freedomn-m and @Lain Thank you. The alert code got fired. Though, it is now not progressing any further from there. Feels like peeling an onion layer by layer.